# Sonata Admin Bundle: Empty entity reference throws exception during entity creation

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, symfony-3.3

I'm new to Sonata Admin Bundle, so this may be something basic. I have an entity `StudentCourse`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Id;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="student_course")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\StudentCourseRepository")
 *
 * Class StudentCourse
 */
class StudentCourse
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Student", inversedBy="studentCourses")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $student;
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="studentCourses")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $course;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     */
    private $startedAt;


    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStartedAt()
    {
        return $this->startedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $startedAt
     */
    public function setStartedAt($startedAt)
    {
        $this->startedAt = $startedAt;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getStudent() {
        return $this->student;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $student
     */
    public function setStudent($student) {
        $this->student = $student;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCourse() {
        return $this->course;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $course
     */
    public function setCourse($course) {
        $this->course = $course;
    }
}
```

And `StudentCourseAdmin`:

```
namespace AppBundle\Admin;

use AppBundle\Entity\Course;
use AppBundle\Entity\Student;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\AbstractAdmin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\CoreBundle\Validator\ErrorElement;

class StudentCourseAdmin extends AbstractAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('student', 'entity', [
            'class' => Student::class,
            'choice_label' => 'lastName',
            'required' => true,
        ]);
        $formMapper->add('course', 'entity', [
            'class' => Course::class,
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'required' => true,
        ]);
        $formMapper->add('startedAt', 'date', [
            'required' => true,
        ]);
    }

    protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
    {
        //$datagridMapper->add('student');
        //$datagridMapper->add('course');
    }

    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
        $listMapper->add('student');
        $listMapper->add('course');
        $listMapper->add('startedAt');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
    {
        $errorElement
            ->with('student')
                ->assertNotBlank()
                ->assertNotNull()
            ->end()
            ->with('course')
                ->assertNotBlank()
                ->assertNotNull()
            ->end();

    }
}
```

In services:

```
app.admin.student_course:
    class: AppBundle\Admin\StudentCourseAdmin
    arguments: [~, AppBundle\Entity\StudentCourse, ~]
    tags:
        - { name: sonata.admin, manager_type: orm, label: StudentCourse }
    public: true
```

There are no `Course`s available. When I try to create an entity `StudentCourse` with an empty `Course` field, I'm getting an exception. It is kinda expected and not expected - what I don't understand is why there is no validation for this, just brutal exception - am I missing something? How this situation could be handled more gracefully?

I'm using Symfony `3.3.6`and Sonata Admin Bundle `3.21.0`.

The exception I'm getting is:

> An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template
>   ("Notice: Undefined index: course_id") in
>   "SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:base_edit_form.html.twig".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you created an entity for something that can be handle with a ManyToMany. but your problem probably its here:

```
/**
 * @Id
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="studentCourses")
 *** @Assert\NotBlank()** <---- here !!!
 */
private $course;
```

Try this:

```
    /**
     * @Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Course", inversedBy="studentCourses")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="course_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable= true)
     */
    private $course;
```

after that you have to update your schema by console with :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force
```

you'd probably wanna take a look at this: 
http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html